# PHP Sql Server COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, transactions

in this code i was planning to insert a data to table named "User" and then after data inserted it will generated some computed column (UserId) and i will get that computed column value to insert data to another table called "Officials" this was done using transaction. the first insert on User table is okay (already tried deleting the second insert and it work fine) but when it get to the second insert to "Officials" table it show error like this :

```
"errorInfo":["07002",0,"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error"]
```

here is the code:

```
try{
    $database->beginTransaction();
    $query = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO [User](Email, Name) 
                                 VALUES(:email , :name)");
    $query->bindParam(':email', $jsonData->email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':name', $jsonData->name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
    if($rowCount<1){
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(400);
        $response->setIsSuccess(false);
        $response->addMessage("Failed to Register1");
        $response->send();
        exit;
    }else{
        //Error start from here
        $lastInsertId = $database->lastInsertId();
        $query = $database->query("SELECT UserId 
                                    FROM [dbo].[User] 
                                    WHERE ID = :lastInsert");
        $query->bindParam(':lastInsert', $lastInsertId , PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();

        $result = $query -> fetch();
        $userId = $result ["UserId"];
        $query = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO Officials(UserId , UnitId) 
                                      VALUES(:userId , :unitId)");
        $query->bindParam(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':unitId', $jsonData->unit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
        if($rowCount<1){
            throw("Failed to Register / Signup");
        }else{
            $database->commit();
            $response = new Response();
            $response->setStatusCode(200);
            $response->setIsSuccess(true);
            $response->addMessage("Success");
            $response->send();
            exit;
        }
    }
} catch(Exception $ex){
    $database->rollBack();
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setStatusCode(400);
    $response->setIsSuccess(false);
    $response->addMessage($ex);
    $response->send();
    exit;
}
```

thankyou, any advice will be really appreciated since im really new at php.

Comment: Basic debugging. Which statement causes the error? Is it `$lastInsertId = $database->lastInsertId();`?

Comment: Not sure, but I thought SQL Server params need to be passed with an `@` like `@userId`. By the way `lastInsertId` is probably not reliable, you should return `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` from the first insert

Answer (score 0):

I end up using the following SQL Server command @@IDENTITY instead of lastinserId from PDO, i dont know if this is the right way but it works for me.

```
$query = $database->query("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE ID = @@IDENTITY");
```